# Remove Sidebar from Product Category Pages | Older fixes don't seam to be working

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have looked at every single piece of information published and none seam to apply to this current version of woocommerce. It looks absolutely horrible with the woo default sidebar and I have no "shop" file in my directory to make changes to nor can i find any sidebar.php file in woocommerce. Somebody please give me a hand! If I can even just hide it with a CSS code please give it to me and tell me where to place it. Ive put a lot of work into this and that sidebar just looks terrible. I'm not very knowledgeable with wordpress so as much help as possible is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an online version of your site ? It would be easier to tell you where to change any CSS.

Comment: yes have a staging environment http://eee.923.myftpupload.com/ have tried every post as i have understood and the backend files seam to be completely different. Thanks! I noticed there was a recent update.

Comment: Just to be sure, it's the bar on the left of product pages, which contains the list of pages, archives, etc ?

Comment: I don't believe there is one on the left... the default sidebar only on the products page which is on the right... the Search, Page (which has all draft pages listed as well), Categories, and Archives sidebar.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant on the right.

Comment: yeah exactly thats the one. There is plenty of documentation on how to remove it however I must be an update past the fix. My directory is completely different.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick fix, but it would be ideal to remove the display of the sidebar totally. Calling it and hiding it with CSS makes unecessary requests to the database. You'd have to look in the template files if there's something like 'get_sidebar()", and comment/remove it.

Anyway, if you put this into any loaded CSS file (say woocommerce.css for example), it should work :

```
#main #sidebar {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: .woocommerce #primary {
  width: 100%;
}
.woocommerce #secondary {
  display: none;
} I had tossed this into my templates.css file and it didn't accomplish anything but im about to look through the directory again and try that. thanks for the quick response

Comment: unfortunately still no luck :(